# Thread-safe TBB::concurrent_hash_map erase

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, tbb

I am searching a solution for a thread-safe map, but include tbb all content libraries are not thread-safe for erase, clear functions.I dont want to use mutexes because of performance issues.I am searching it on internet for a long time but still i couldnt find any example about this, and also i have a bad english for long articles.I searched a lot of things something like const are thread-safe for c++11 but i couldnt figure out.

I tried this for copy the map but its not thread-safe too.

```
 __forceinline ActiveMap & GetActiveMap() { return m_activeCollection; }
```

This code crashing when i tried to copy map while another thread is in it.

Comment: You are wrong, `tbb::concurrent_hash_map::erase` is thread-safe

Comment: whole container operations like assignment or copy are not thread-safe. You can use `tbb::spin_rw_lock` in order to protect it for the sake of taking the snapshot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(I'm guessing you are using visual c++ because of the `__forceinline` keyword`)

1. Visual studio 2013 (and I guess Visual studio 2015) comes with small set of concurrent data structures. the header `<concurrent_unordered_map.h>` implements concurrent map which you can use.
2. try to profile your application with locks. Slim reader writer lock usually is not so bad and might be enough.

Comment: I am using visual studio 2015, will i use reader lock for find, begin, end and use write for insert and erase right?

Comment: use it for anything. use the read mode for every function which is `const` and write mode for ebery function which is not `const`. amazing how `const` suggested thread safetyness since the language just came to being!

Comment: i added a new answer and i writed a code, do you know anymore trick to increase performance?

Comment: TBB has the same `concurrent_unordered_map` class

Comment: But `concurrent_unordered_map` has not a thread-safe `unsafe_erase()`